# Issues getting value from hidden input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
   var targetName = $(this).attr('name');
   var target = $(document).find(':hidden[name=targetName]').val();
   alert(target);
});
```

I want to get the value of the hidden input with the same name as the checkbox (on change)
My issue here is that the alert only results in "undefined", but if I alert the part without "val()" it gives me an object back. All my jQuery code is inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Also I tired to put my script code under my html, but without no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate your variable and add double quotes:

```
var target = $(document).find(':hidden[name="'+ targetName + '"]').val();
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you need quotes around the attribute selector like `:hidden[name="' + targetName + '"]'`?

Comment: @entropic yes, you're right. Thanks for spotting. Updated my answer

Comment: @entropic You don't always need them. "Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string." http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/